# Trying to add image URLs to a list for webscraping, using a for loop and append list

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I have the following code which is producing a logic error. I am seeking to simply scrape the image URLs and put them in the list, and return the list (which should contain *multiple* image URLs).

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,url_for #importing flask class
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


app = Flask(__name__) #setting app variable to instance of flask class

@app.route('/') #this is what we type into our browser to go to pages. we create these using routes
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    images=imagescrape()
    return render_template('home.html',images=images)


def imagescrape():
    images=[]
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry,_Duke_of_Sussex')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images: 
        images=image.append(image['src']+'\n')
    return images
```

On rendering the home.html page with the variable `images` (which is returning the result of the function) I get

```
None
```

I tried:

```
    for image in images: 
        images=image['src']+'\n')
    return images
```

but this only returns the *first* image URL.

Can someone point out the error please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get `None`

This is because:

> ```
> images=image.append(...)
> ```

The `append` method of a list returns `None`, therefore assigning it to `images` sets it to `None` (however it surprises me that this doesn't give an error because `image` is not a list and doesn't even have an `append` method).

---

You seem to be a bit confused by the variable names you have chosen and how iterating over a list and appending to a list works.

There should be *two* lists, which you both named `images`:

1. The list which you build up in a loop and return eventually
2. The result of `bs.find_all`

Here is how you should do it correctly:

```
def imagescrape():
    # List 1 (TARGET):
    result_images=[]
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry,_Duke_of_Sussex')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # List 2 (SOURCE):
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
               # ^^^^^^ SOURCE list
        result_images.append(image['src']+'\n')
      # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TARGET list
    return result_images
```

---

If you have a pattern

```
target_list = []
for item in source_list:
    target_list.append(process(item))
```

you can also transform this to a list comprehension:

```
target_list = [process(item) for item in source_list]
```

In your case you can apply this as follows, which makes the code a bit clearer in my opinion:

```
def imagescrape():
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry,_Duke_of_Sussex')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    return [image['src']+'\n' for image in images]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def imagescrape():
    final_images=[]
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry,_Duke_of_Sussex')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images: 
        final_images.append(image['src']+'\n')
    return final_images
```